# Having trouble moving uploaded file into randomly generated folder

Tags: php

Working on a social networking site that lets the user upload a default photo into a randomly generated folder. Everything works up until the fuction move uploaded file. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Hosted on bluehost.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_FILES['listingpic'])){
    if(@$_FILES['listingpic']['type']=="image/jpeg"||@$_FILES['listingpic']['type']=="image/png"||@$_FILES['listingpic']['type']=="image/gif"){
        if(@$_FILES['listingpic']['size']<1048576){
            $chars = "abcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
            $rand_dir_name = substr (str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
            echo "new directory: ".$rand_dir_name;
            mkdir("userdata/listingpics/$rand_dir_name/") or die("directory error");
            move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['listingpic']['tmp_name'], "userdata/listingpics/".$_FILES['listingname']['name']) or die("Failed to move file.");
        } else echo "File must not exceed 1MB.";
    } else echo "File must be a JPEG, PNG, or GIF image."; 
  } else echo "Not set.";
?>
```

Comment: bracing techniques? Also, the directory is created on the site just fine. When I try to move the file it says it fails.

Comment: check your listingpics folder; it's most likely in there. If it isn't, then none of your folders have permissions to be written to, nor will it be written to any other sub-folder from hereon in.

Comment: its not the randomly generator directory is but no pictures. It dies and echos failed to move file

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Plus, you're not using `$rand_dir_name` in your `move_uploaded_file()` function.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I removed that for debugging and it didn't work even after I removed rand_dir_name

Comment: try removing the `@` symbols from your code, those are error suppressors. also, mkdir usually requires a parameter for the folder's permissions be passed as and for example `mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);` - By not doing so, your folder(s) may not have the proper permissions set; it's worth looking into and to see what all your folders and sub-folders permissions are. If one in there cannot pass, then it won't let you or probably won't let you write to another sub-folder. I can only offer suggestions at this point.

Comment: Now, if your form doesn't have a POST method, forms usually fail silently if a POST method isn't implied; it defaults to GET if omitted and make sure the form has a valid enctype. Best I can do at this point.

Comment: `"userdata/listingpics/".$_FILES['listingname']` should read as `"userdata/listingpics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES['listingname']` btw. and maybe even `mkdir("userdata/listingpics/$rand_dir_name/")` to `mkdir("userdata/listingpics/$rand_dir_name")` with no trailing slash.

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: listingname in /home/urbanas8/public_html/list_property/upload.php on line 9730 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/urbanas8/public_html/list_property/upload.php on line 9730 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpUA1QRj' to 'userdata/listingpics/IGdYgBn8Lwhr1qS/' in /home/urbanas8/public_html/list_property/upload.php on line 9730"

Comment: Oh ok, listingpic not listing name, for some reason when I copied your code it worked thanks fred!

Comment: You're welcome Michael. I posted an answer below if you wish to accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"userdata/listingpics/".$_FILES['listingname']` should read as
`"userdata/listingpics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES['listingname']`

Plus, `mkdir("userdata/listingpics/$rand_dir_name/")` to
`mkdir("userdata/listingpics/$rand_dir_name")` with no trailing slash.

You didn't include `$rand_dir_name` in there.

Comment: listingpic not listingname, for some reason when I copied your code it worked thanks fred!

Comment: @MichaelCollins You're welcome Michael, glad to have been of help, *cheers*